# how to plot against time using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data and I want to plot Speed5A and Predicted (each one with a specific color) against TimeA1:

```
data <- structure(list(TimeA1 = structure(1:20, .Label = c("06:00:00", 
"06:05:00", "06:10:00", "06:15:00", "06:20:00", "06:25:00", "06:30:00", 
"06:35:00", "06:40:00", "06:45:00", "06:50:00", "06:55:00", "07:00:00", 
"07:05:00", "07:10:00", "07:15:00", "07:20:00", "07:25:00", "07:30:00", 
"07:35:00", "07:40:00", "07:45:00", "07:50:00", "07:55:00", "08:00:00", 
"08:05:00", "08:10:00", "08:15:00", "08:20:00", "08:25:00", "08:30:00", 
"08:35:00", "08:40:00", "08:45:00", "08:50:00", "08:55:00", "09:00:00", 
"09:05:00", "09:10:00", "09:15:00", "09:20:00", "09:25:00", "09:30:00", 
"09:35:00", "09:40:00", "09:45:00", "09:50:00", "09:55:00", "10:00:00", 
"10:05:00", "10:10:00", "10:15:00", "10:20:00", "10:25:00", "10:30:00", 
"10:35:00", "10:40:00", "10:45:00", "10:50:00", "10:55:00", "11:00:00", 
"11:05:00", "11:10:00", "11:15:00", "11:20:00", "11:25:00", "11:30:00", 
"11:35:00", "11:40:00", "11:45:00", "11:50:00", "11:55:00", "12:00:00", 
"12:05:00", "12:10:00", "12:15:00", "12:20:00", "12:25:00", "12:30:00", 
"12:35:00", "12:40:00", "12:45:00", "12:50:00", "12:55:00", "13:00:00", 
"13:05:00", "13:10:00", "13:15:00", "13:20:00", "13:25:00", "13:30:00", 
"13:35:00", "13:40:00", "13:45:00", "13:50:00", "13:55:00", "14:00:00", 
"14:05:00", "14:10:00", "14:15:00", "14:20:00", "14:25:00", "14:30:00", 
"14:35:00", "14:40:00", "14:45:00", "14:50:00", "14:55:00", "15:00:00", 
"15:05:00", "15:10:00", "15:15:00", "15:20:00", "15:25:00", "15:30:00", 
"15:35:00", "15:40:00", "15:45:00", "15:50:00", "15:55:00", "16:00:00", 
"16:05:00", "16:10:00", "16:15:00", "16:20:00", "16:25:00", "16:30:00", 
"16:35:00", "16:40:00", "16:45:00", "16:50:00", "16:55:00", "17:00:00", 
"17:05:00", "17:10:00", "17:15:00", "17:20:00", "17:25:00", "17:30:00", 
"17:35:00", "17:40:00", "17:45:00", "17:50:00", "17:55:00", "18:00:00", 
"18:05:00", "18:10:00", "18:15:00", "18:20:00", "18:25:00", "18:30:00", 
"18:35:00", "18:40:00", "18:45:00", "18:50:00", "18:55:00", "19:00:00"
), class = "factor"), Speed5A = c(109.412, 109.412, 106.194, 
85.277, 77.232, 88.495, 88.495, 91.713, 90.104, 78.841, 41.834, 
46.661, 37.007, 51.488, 43.443, 54.706, 70.796, 45.052, 56.315, 
25.744), predicted = c(109, 106, 107, 99, 85, 65, 84, 76, 83, 
82, 46, 53, 33, 55, 38, 61, 62, 46, 46, 38)), row.names = 158:177, class = "data.frame")
```

Can anyone help me to have the required result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pivot to long format and use `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
data %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -TimeA1) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = TimeA1, y = value, group = name, color = name)) + 
         geom_line()
```

---

Or another option is `gather`

```
data %>%
   gather(name, value, -TimeA1) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = TimeA1, y = value, group = name, color = name)) + 
         geom_line()
```

Comment: for some reason pivot_longer does not work on my R. Could you please give another approach?

Comment: That works. However, the time is still messy, can we show specific intervals so it become tidier?

Comment: @mustafa can you please specify the cut intervals

Comment: 06:00:00, 10:10:00, 13:00:00, 16:00:00, 19:00:00

Comment: @mustafa you can try with `data %>% mutate(TimeA1 = as.POSIXct(as.character(TimeA1), format = "%H:%M:%S")) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -TimeA1) %>%  ggplot(aes(x = TimeA1, y = value, group = name, color = name)) +  geom_line() + scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M:%S", breaks = date_breaks('4 hour'))`

Comment: it says "Error in date_breaks("4 hour") : could not find function "date_breaks" "

Comment: @mustafa sorry, it is from `library(scales)`

Comment: Thanks akrun, I have used a manual approach and it worked.